# Hide duplicate post on article page - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm displaying a article on my page in Wordpress. Then right below that article, Im doing a foreach loop and displaying latest articles. Here is how it looks:

[image]

As you can see, "Jeffs Wedding Surprise" displays again in the bottom articles. How can I make it so the same article wont display again in my foreach loop that I'm viewing right now.

Here is how Im looping through the **"Similar articles"** at the bottom and my featured article:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ){
            while( have_posts(['posts_per_page'=>100]) ){
                $articles = the_post();
                $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($articles);
                $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
                $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
        ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="article-heading">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="article-background">
                <img src="<?=$thumb_url;?>">
                <?php
                $title = get_the_title();
                $content = the_content();
                if(strlen($content)>0){?>
                    <div class="article-details">
                        <?php $content ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>


        <div class="similar-section">
            <h3>Similar Articles</h3>
        </div>
        <?php foreach (get_posts(['post_type' => 'add_article', 'posts_per_page'=>3]) as $articles) {
            $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($articles);
            $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
            $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
            $url_to_project = "/previous_work/".$articles->post_name;
            ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="article-link" href="<?=$url_to_project;?>">
                        <div class="single-article-photo">
                            <img src="<?=$thumb_url;?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-article">
                            <h6><?= $articles->post_title ?></h6>
                            <p><?= substr($articles->post_content,0,200) ?> <span style="text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: underline">(Read More)</span>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was supposed to do in the foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach (get_posts(['post_type' => 'add_article', 'posts_per_page'=>3,'exclude'=>[get_the_ID()]]) as $articles) { ?>
```

That will exclude the current article in the **"Similar articles"** section on bottom of page.

Answer (score 1):

You can add condition to check the title/id of main article not display in similar articles.

In main article code

```
$title = get_the_title(); // title of main article
```

For similar articles

```
 foreach (get_posts(['post_type' => 'add_article', 'posts_per_page'=>3]) as $articles) {
    if($title!=$articles->post_title){
      // display article 
    }
}
```